# Actual difference between end of line and end of file under windows?

Tags: c++

I understand EOF and EOL but when I was reading [this question](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylv=3?qid=20110416085509AAPnEqL)  (second part of answer) and i got my concepts broken :
Specially the para :

> It won't stop taking input until it finds the end of file(**cin uses
>   stdin, which is treated very much like a file**)

so i want to know when we do some thing like in c++ under windows :
`std::cin>>int_var;` , and we press enter , this end the input but according to reference link it should only stop taking input after hitting `ctrl+z`.

So i would love to know how `std::*stream` deal with EOF and EOL.

Second part:
please have a look at this example :

> ```
> std::cin.getline(char_array_of_size_256 ,256);
> cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
> cout << "artist is " << artist << endl;
> ```

If i remove `std::cin.ignore()` it simply stops taking input (which is known case) but when i keep it , it waits for a new input which is ended by `'\n'` . But it should simply clear up stream rather then waiting for any new input ending-up with '\n'.

Thanks for giving you time)

Comment: Are you aware of that EOF usually refers to the condition of the file reaching its end, but is not actually a part of the file data (which can be of any combination of bytes), while EOL is usually referred to an implemetnation specific character(sequence) denoting the end of a line?

Comment: @PlasmaHH : yes i know EOF signal is signaled to program by OS. but can you explain 1st part of question?

Comment: Please ask separate questions for separate, well, questions. Don't just ask them as separate "parts" here

Comment: @jalf I apologize for this , I'll keep this in mind from next time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

End-of-line and end-of-file are very different concepts.

End-of-line is really just another input character (or character sequence) that can appear anywhere in an input stream.  If you're reading input one character at a time from a text stream, end-of-line simply means that you'll see a new-line (`'\n'`) character.  Some input routines treat this character specially; for example, it tells `getline` to stop reading.  (Other routines treat `' '` specially; there's no fundamental difference.)

Different operating systems use different conventions for marking the end of a line.  On Linux and other Unix-like systems, the end of a line in a file is marked with a single ASCII linefeed (`LF`, '\n') character.  When reading from a keyboard, both LF and CR are typically mapped to `'\n'` (try typing either `Enter`, `Control-J`, or `Control-M`).  On Windows, the end of a line in a file is marked with a `CR`-`LF` pair (`\r\n`).  The C and C++ I/O systems (or the lower-level software they operate on top of) map all these markers to a single `'\n'` character, so your program doesn't have to worry about all the possible variations.

End-of-file is not a character, it's a *condition* that says there are no more characters available to be read.  Different things can trigger this condition.  When you're reading from a disk file, it's just the physical end of the file.  When you're reading from a keyboard on Windows, `control-Z` denotes end-of-file; on Unix/Linux, it's typically `control-D` (though it can be configured differently).

(You'll *usually* have an end-of-line (character sequence) just before end-of-file, but not always; input can sometimes end in an unterminated line, on some systems.)

Different input routines have different ways of indicating that they've seen an end-of-file condition.  Read the documentation for each one for the details.

As for `EOF`, that's a macro defined in `<stdio.h>` or `<cstdio>`.  It expands to a negative integer constant (typically -1) that's returned by some functions to *indicate* that they've reached an end-of-file condition.

**EDIT**: For example, suppose you're reading from a text file containing two lines:

```
one
two
```

Let's say you're using C's `getchar()`, `getc()`, or `fgetc()` function to read one character at a time.  The values returned on successive calls will be:

```
'o', 'n', 'e', '\n', 't', 'w', 'o', '\n', EOF
```

Or, in numeric form (on a typical system):

```
111, 110, 101, 10, 116, 119, 111, 10, -1
```

Each `'\n'`, or 10 (0x0a) is a new-line character read from the file.  The final `-1` is the value of EOF; this isn't a character, but an indication that there are no more characters to be read.

Higher-level input routines, like C's `fgets()` and C++'s `std::cin >> s` or `std::getline(std::cin, s)`, are built on top of this mechanism.

Comment: Can you please explain what did you mean in this line? : "If you're reading input one character at a time from a text stream,        **end-of-line simply means that you'll see a new-line ('\n') character** "

Comment: @Hades: I'll add this to my answer, since I need to do some formatting.

Answer (score 4):

#### First "part"

> so i want to know when we do some thing like in c++ under windows : std::cin>>int_var; , and we press enter , this end the input but according to reference link it should only stop taking input after hitting ctrl+z.

No, you're confusing formatted input operations with stream iterators.  The following will use the formatted input operation (`operator>>`) repeatedly until the end of file is reached because the "end iterator" represents the end of the stream.

```
std::vector<int> integers;
std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
    std::istream_iterator<int>(),
    std::back_inserter(integers));
```

If you use the following:

```
int i = 0;
std::cin >> i;
```

in an interactive shell (e.g. in console mode), `std::cin` will block on user input which is acquired line by line.  So, if no data (or only white space) is available, this operation will actually force the user to type a line of input and press the enter key.

However,

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
std::cin >> i >> j;
```

may block on one or two lines of input, depending on what the user types.  In particular, if the user types

```
1<space>2<enter>
```

then the two input operations will be applies using the same line of input.

#### Second "part"

Considering the code snippet:

```
std::cin.getline(char_array_of_size_256 ,256);
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
cout << "artist is " << artist << endl;
```

If the line contains 255 or less lines of character data, `std::cin.getline()` will *consume* the end-of-line character.  Thus, the second line will consume all characters until the next line is completed.  If you want to capture only the current line and ignore all characters past 256, I suggest you use something like:

```
std::cin.getline(char_array_of_size_256 ,256);
if (std::cin.gcount() == 256) {
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
cout << "artist is " << artist << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

On the second part:

When the linked answer said "read into a string", I guess they meant

```
std::string   s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

which always reads **the entire line** into the string `s` (while setting `s` to the proper size).

That way there is nothing left over from the input line to clean up.